# missing something obvious in JMX console insertion

Tags: java, jboss, jmx

I'm following the directions for launching my hello world JMX bean and jboss complains with the following:

```
nested throwable: (java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.testPackage.jmx.TestJmxMBean.<init>())
```

I know I'm missing something REALLY obvious, but can't spot what it is.

Why would it be looking for an init method? the class extends one that has no init method, and when I change the name of the class, it fires a classNotFound, so, I know it's looking at the right class...

If anyone has a good step by step tutorial on creating your first MBean for Jboss JMX console, I'll take that too.

Much obliged.

Comment: Maybe it wants a default no-arg constructor?

Comment: @DrDredel: <init> is stacktrace-speak for a constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try add a no-arg constructor (as requested by NoSuchMethodException)

Answer (score 0):

I was accidentally pointing to the Mbean service, rather than my MBean class in the jboss-service.xml.  I knew it was going to be something really stupid and lo and behold... it was.

In case someone finds this useful, there is no constructor, so this exception is sort of a red herring.

Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Strictly speaking, there is a constructor, the default no-arg constructor java adds when there is nothinng else specified. Funnily enough that's what the code that throws the exception is looking for.